# Send metadata before file with sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm struggling to achieve some "precise" data exchange using sockets. I've a program able to send/receive files using these sockets, and I've prepared it to send in a first stage the **filename** and the **file size**.

Everything seems to work fine, but sometimes the data that is received is not the expected one. My guess is that the data received is that of two "send operations" of the Tx that arrive together, so my intended "parse" of the string received is not correct and it crashes.

Currently my code looks like this for the **receiver**:

```
 while True:
    c, addr = self.s.accept()
    l = c.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        if stage < 2:
            self.__recvHeader(l)
            stage += 1
        else:
            self.f.write(l)
        l = c.recv(1024)
```

Being the `__recvHeader` function:

```
def __recvHeader(self, data):
    line = data.decode("utf-8").split(":")
    if line[0] == "Name":
        self.filename = line[1]
        self.f = open("/tmp/" + self.filename, 'wb')
    elif line[0] == "Size":
        self.size = int(line[1])
    else:
        print("ERROR: " + "".join(line))
```

And the **Tx** does like:

```
# Here I send some headers first, then
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    self.s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
```

With the **sendHeader** function being:

```
def __sendHeader(self, name, value):
    self.s.send((name + ":" + value).encode('utf-8'))
```

The problem to me seems like I cannot set a fixed length for the headers, since file name and file size may change.

Any idea about how to treat this problem, or how could I turn these data in something of fixed size to avoid this problem? This last option would need of a different "parse" IMO as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: I guess you use tcp which is a stream-oriented protocol. One common approach to `achieve some "precise" data exchange` is to divide data stream into messages using some separator or set of separators. Then you will be able to receive data message by message instead of uncertain portions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using TCP/IP sockets. TCP/IP is a streaming protocol and does not know anything about your data structures. If you send a "message" in one `send()` operation, there is no guarantee that it will arrive in one `recv()` operation. Or that a `recv()` operation will receive only one "message". In your case, a header is a message.

So you have to delimit your messages in some way, so that the receiver can correctly receive and parse them. You have basically two options:

1. First send the length (number of bytes) of the header followed by the header data. The receiver first reads the length and then reads that many bytes.
2. Send a delimiter after each header. The receiver reads header data until the delimiter is received.

In the first option you have to think about how to send the length. If you use a multiple byte value, such as a 32-bit value, you might want to convert it to *network-byte order* before sending. See [htonl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.htonl).

In the second option you could `recv()` byte-by-byte but this will be very slow. You might want to use some kind of buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using a socket with: `socket.SOCK_STREAM`! That means the sockets use TCP, which ensures that your data arrives and arrives in order (within reasonable limits of "ensuredness"). If problems persist, read on...

I would first [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) encode your file, in order to remove any quirkiness in the data. base64 uses a [limited alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html#section-1) to encode the data. So adding a marker token that is outside of that alphabet is trivial and safe. You could literally do (pseudo-code):

```
while ('$'.encode('utf-8') not in l):
    l = c.recv(1024)
    # append l to a bytearray or similar
```

And you just send `"$<base64filecontent>$"`.